# How does the compiler know that which overload of std::forward function has to be called?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding

The following signatures are declared as `std::forward` overloads:

```
template<class T> T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& arg) noexcept;
template<class T> T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type&& arg) noexcept;
```

Now, consider the following template function:

```
template<class T> T&& foo_as_always(T&& t)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

If I write:

```
int i = 0;
foo_as_always(i);
```

Then this is how the compiler instantiates `foo_as_always` with `T = int&`:

```
int& foo_as_always(int& t)
{
    // Does it call the first signature of std::forward(int&)
    return std::forward<int&>(t);
}
```

And if I write:

```
foo_as_always(0);
```

Then the compiler instantiates `foo_as_always` with `T = int`:

```
int&& foo_as_always(int&& t)
{
    // Does it call the second signature of std::forward(int&&)?
    return std::forward<int>(t);
}
```

In both cases, the `t` variable is l-value in any expression. How does compiler know which overload of the `std::forward` function has to be called?

Comment: Read about [universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're providing the template argument explicitly (you're providing the `<T>`); there's no type deduction.

In the call `foo_as_always(i);`, `i` is an lvalue so `T` is deduced to `int &`, and this is what you provide to `std::forward`.

In the call `foo_as_always(0);`, `0` is an rvalue and so `T` is deduced to `int`, and this is again what you provide to `std::forward`.

In both cases, it ends up calling the first overload, of course, since `t` is an lvalue, as you say. But the return type differs - in the first case, it's `int& &&`, so `int&`, in the second case, it's `int &&`.